# User experience / interaction design for elderly people using banking apps

Tags: mobile-application, older-users, online-banking

We are currently designing a mobile interface for elderly people for the banking industry.

Is there a need for tweaking the standard (not applying the best practices, for example: tooltip for mobile)? Because they don't usually get something very quickly.

The data says that these are the people that let others use the functionality to complete a task, they cannot actually use products that are too cluttered - based on usability testing, they are easily overwhelmed with so much information all at once. What are the best practices we can use to actually help them understand/use a functionality better?

What would you recommend on designing such? Any inputs are very much welcome.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What does `"tweaking the standard"` mean? Could you edit your question and try to better explain what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Welcome to User Experience Stack Exchange. Your question seems a bit broad to me, since it covers usability and/or accessibility for banking apps for elderly people without focusing on any specific aspect. Do you think you could narrow down your question a bit, possibly splitting it up into multiple posts? And are you looking for advice based on research?

Comment: Ok I will thank you very much!

Comment: yes please. Looking for advice based on research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to "tweaking the standard". If we are talking about mobile apps the "standard" tends to be that particular OS' guidelines.

In both the case of Apple iOS14 and Material design, the majority of the components, size of the buttons for touch, standard text sizes etc have been defined so the majority of users can experience no issues using the mobile device.

However, in your question you're talking about "clutter" and too much information. This sounds more of a case of showing too much content to the users rather than using the wrong design components.

I would recommend you look into things like [Progressive Disclosure](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/) and the [10 UI Heuristics](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) as points of reference that might help you display content in a timely and helpful way.

Lastly, and this might be more of a dev point rather than a design one, ensure that your app supports the native OS' accessibility settings.

A lot of older users tend to opt for larger text, contrast options, or even screen-reading for their devices. Ensuring your app can still function, navigate, and display content properly with users that may have altered those settings will definitely improve the usability for quite a few of your elderly users.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to define 'older people': 80 year olds will behave differently from 40 year olds.

Eyesight starts to decline during the 40s decade: so you'll get 48 year olds complaining about the text being too small.

( people who haven't been lifelong glasses wearers tend to put off wearing glasses as their eyesight gets worse, they'll blame the interface rather than give in to glasses !)

So 40 somethings are 'older people'.

Comment: 40-60 range for 'older people'

Comment: Will consider the eyesight. Thank you very much for this